# Error installing scipy

Tags: arch-linux, python, manjaro, pip

I'm on Manjaro trying to install scipy in virtualenv using pip. I get [this error](http://dpaste.com/18AKEEP). How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to download and install OpenBLAS. Download latest stable version from https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/zipball/master. Extract and run `make` and `make install`.

You will need `gfortran` to compile.

Make sure you have numpy installed as well, you  should be able to install that from an archive.

Comment: Can't find gfortan in aur

Comment: @Lynob https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/gcc-fortran/